# Trying to get 2 images side by side and be centered (they are always drawn left justified)

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm putting together the layout for my app. On the bottom I wanted to have 2 `ImageView` side by side to be centered, but they are left justified. I set the gravity to center, not working.

Xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#ff29245c"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ScrollView 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent">  

        <LinearLayout 
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <ImageView                  
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/parschute"
                android:id="@+id/ok"    
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginTop="12px" />  

            <LinearLayout 
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

            // WOULD LIKE THE 2 IMAGEVIEWS BELOW TO BE NEXT TO BE ON SAME LINE AND CENTERED

                <ImageView                  
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/pulldown"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"/>        

                    <ImageView                  
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/camera"  
                    android:layout_gravity="center"/>        

            </LinearLayout>                 
        </LinearLayout>        
    </ScrollView>         
 </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: A mock png of what you're trying to achieve would be useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess this is what you're trying.-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#666600"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:background="#0000FF" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:background="#00FFFF" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Which produces this result.-

[image: Layout screenshot]

(notice I took the screenshot of the bottom half of the layout)

Comment: This can be achieved without the relative layout.